# What type of distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

The number of flaws in the process of producing sheet metal follows a Poisson
process with rate λ = .1 flaws per square foot.
a. Let X equal the number of flaws in a 5 square foot section of sheet metal.
Identify by name the distribution of X including its parameter(s).

I think is Poisson with rate $\lambda = 0.5$. Is this correct?

Comment: A 5sqft region has area 25, so the expected number of flaws (and the mean of the associated Poisson random variable) would be 2.5.

Comment: @Math1000 I thought a 5 sqft region had area... 5 sqft. Would you be alluding to a region delimited by a square of side 5 ft?

Comment: Indeed, looks like I got the units mixed up.

Comment: Yes, this is correct.